# Showing values from a foreign key in a template

Tags: python, django

I would like to show the values from a foreign key in my template but they appear in blank when trying to render it. The values i am trying to show are the ones coming from the Paciente attribute, which is connected to the Patient model in another app through a Foreign Key, i will show my attempt in achieving this but failing, can you please help me or tell me what i am doing wrong:(

## Views

```
class AppointmentIndexView(ListView):
    model = Consults
    template_name = 'appointments_index.html'
    context_object_name = 'consults'
    ordering = ['Fecha']

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        queryset.filter(Fecha=datetime.date.today())
        return queryset
```

## Models

```
class Consults(models.Model):
    #General Consult Info
    Paciente = models.ForeignKey(Patient,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Fecha = models.DateField()
    Motivo = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True)
    Padecimiento = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True)
    #Main Patient Info
    Presion = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True,null=True)
    Temperatura = models.FloatField(blank=True,null=True)
    Peso = models.FloatField(blank=True,null=True)
    Talla = models.FloatField(blank=True,null=True)
    #Any Exams done before
    Estudios = models.ImageField(upload_to='studies',blank=True)
    #Interrogatory by System
    Digestivo = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
    Endocrino = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
    Renal = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
    Linfativo = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
    Respiratorio = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
    #Physical Exploration
    Cabeza = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
    Torax = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
    #Diagnose
    CIE_10 = models.ForeignKey(CIE_10,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,blank=True,null=True)
    Detalle_de_Codigo = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
    Diagnostico = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
    Procedimiento = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
    Analisis = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
    #Treatment
    Medicamento = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
    Descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
    Uso = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
    Dosis = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
    Acciones = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
```

## Template

```
{%extends 'base.html'%}
{%load staticfiles%}
{%block body_block%}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{%static 'appointments/css/appointments_index.css'%}">
    {%if consults%}
    <h1 id="Heading">Consultas <h5 id="Date">{% now "j F Y" %}</h5></h1>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <th>Codigo de Paciente</th>
                <th>Paciente</th>
                <th>Fecha</th>
                <th>Motivo</th>
                <th>Padecimiento</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {%for consult in consults%}
                    {%for patient in consults.Patient.all%}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{patient.Codigo}}</td>
                            <td>{{patient.Nombres}} {{patient.Apellidos}}</td>
                            <td>{{consult.Fecha}}</td>
                            <td>{{consult.Motivo}}</td>
                            <td>{{consult.Padecimiento}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    {%endfor%}
                {%endfor%}
            </tbody>
        </table>

    {%else%}
    <h1 id="noregisters">No existen registros de consultas aun.</h1>
    {%endif%}

    <button id="Add"><a class="fas fa-plus" href="{%url 'addappointment'%}"></a></button>
{%endblock%}
```

Comment: Isn't is consults.Paciente.all ? instead of consults.Patient.all ?

Comment: This didn't worked also:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Paciente` object relation in `Consult` model isn't iterable. That relation is One to Many relations which mean Patience has Many `Consult`.

```
class Consults(models.Model):
     Paciente = models.ForeignKey(Patient,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="consults")
```

You can iterate `consults` backward relation from `Paciente` object

```
instance = Paciente.objects.first()
for consult in instance.consults.all():
    # Do everyting with consult object
```

You can iterate backward relation also in template

```
{% for consult in instance.consults.all %}
    # Do everyting with consult object
{% endfor %}
```

Or you can do the following to invoke `Paciente` object directly

```
{%for consult in consults%} 
    <tr> 
      <td>{{consult.Paciente.Codigo}}</td> 
      <td>{{patient.Paciente.Nombres}} {{patient.Paciente.Apellidos}}</td> 
      <td>{{consult.Fecha}}</td> 
      <td>{{consult.Motivo}}</td> 
      <td>{{consult.Padecimiento}}</td> 
    </tr> 
{%endfor%}
```

Comment: So i should change my models, turn the Foreign Key into a OnetoMany field to get access to those values?

Answer (score 0):

`{%for patient in consults.Patient.all%}` should be `{% for patient in consult.patient_set.all %}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your inner for loop from `{%for patient in consults.Patient.all%}` to `{% for patient in consults.Paciente_set.all %}`. You can change `Paciente_set` name with adding `related_name` attribute in ForeignKey definition.